# Overlay Figcaption on Img

Tags: html, css, image

I run a website and I am trying to add copyright information to the top-left corner of an image. The `img` element is `float:left;` and the `figcaption` element is located after the `img` element, but I have a few issues:

1) If I use the `position:absolute` CSS style on the `figcaption` element, it will overlay the caption on the image, like I want. However, if I have multiple images listed one after each other, the captions no longer go to the top-left corner and may be positioned in random positions on the page.[image]

2) If I use the `position:relative` CSS style on the `figcaption` element, it will place the caption next to the image. This can be fixed when I add `left:-410px;` to the `figcaption` CSS because all images are the same width. However, the `p` element that is setup to wrap beside the `img` element will leave a gap were the `figcaption` was originally positioned.[image]

My question is, how can I get the `figcaption` in the top-left corner of the `img` element without affecting the `p` element's wrapping or indenting?

---

Code sample: https://jsfiddle.net/ComputerWhiz/mp9sdqq3/1/

Comment: Please post a complete code example in your question.

Comment: Put Image and figcaption inside div with position relative and figcaption position absolute. Position absolute is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor.

Comment: I'm assuming there is a `figure` element in there somewhere..otherwise you shouldn't be using `figcaption`...yeah...code sample required.

Comment: Here is the code sample on JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ComputerWhiz/mp9sdqq3/1/

Comment: @j08691 ^ There is the code sample

Comment: Your position: relative is messing things up. I have a fiddle that fixes it, but it's not ideal at all. https://jsfiddle.net/ChrisG87/mp9sdqq3/3/

Comment: "*in your question*"

Comment: @Paulie_D ^^ There is the code sample.

Comment: @ChrisG Nothing is changed in the Fiddle that you shared.

Comment: @ComputerWhiz: Sorry, I always test first in inspector and I always forget to edit the actual code in Fiddle hahaha. Here's the new link: https://jsfiddle.net/ChrisG87/mp9sdqq3/4/ Sorry again :)

Comment: @ChrisG It looks like it works, but why it is not ideal?

Comment: If you look closely, you'll see that you have to set the top in px, which means it's not responsive if you change your browser size. Other then that, it is good.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe this is what you're after:

```css
img {
  width: 400px;
  clear: left;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

figcaption {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  max-width: 400px;
  font-size: 10px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

figure {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<figure><img src="http://www.aviatorcameragear.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/placeholder.jpg">
  <figcaption>Copyright Here</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure><img src="http://www.aviatorcameragear.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/placeholder.jpg">
  <figcaption>Copyright Here</figcaption>
</figure>
<p>This test should be wrapped around the image and should not be affected by the figcaption.This test should be wrapped around the image and should not be affected by the figcaption.This test should be wrapped around the image and should not be affected
  by the figcaption.This test should be wrapped around the image and should not be affected by the figcaption.This test should be wrapped around the image and should not be affected by the figcaption.This test should be wrapped around the image and should
  not be affected by the figcaption.This test should be wrapped around the image and should not be affected by the figcaption.This test should be wrapped around the image and should not be affected by the figcaption.This test should be wrapped around
  the image and should not be affected by the figcaption.This test should be wrapped around the image and should not be affected by the figcaption.This test should be wrapped around the image and should not be affected by the figcaption.This test should
  be wrapped around the image and should not be affected by the figcaption.This test should be wrapped around the image and should not be affected by the figcaption.This test should be wrapped around the image and should not be affected by the figcaption.This
  test should be wrapped around the image and should not be affected by the figcaption.This test should be wrapped around the image and should not be affected by the figcaption.</p>
```

You should position the `<figcaption>` element absolutely, and then position the `<figure>` relatively. Absolutely positioned elements are positioned with respect to their closest positioned ancestor, which is why you want the relative positioning on the figure. Then, float the figures instead of the images.

Comment: How would you get the figcaption horizontal centered?

Comment: margin: 0 auto; ?