# How to align image in the center of the screen and add text in the left bottom corner of the image

Tags: html, css, formatting

I'm building a simple website right now and faced a small issue. How do I align picture (iMessage text with blue bubble) in the center of the screen so and place a text in the bottom left corner of the image (text is **Read** + time)?

```html
<style>
   html, body
{
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

div {
    position:relative;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

div img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
}
</style>

<head>
    <div>
        <img src="myimage.jpg"></img>
    </div>
</head>
```

But how do I add text in the bottom left corner right below the image?

Comment: I advise you to read more tuto and online ressources before asking ... your code is completely wrong and invalid ... and by simply searching "centring element with CSS" on google you will get a ton of code

Comment: I think [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019577/overlay-figcaption-on-img) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work for you...

```html
<style>
   html, body
{
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.centered{
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

</style>
<head>
    <div class="centered">
       <img src="myimage.jpg"></img>
       <p>tester</p> 
    </div>
</head>
```

Although I completely agree with Temani, there are lots of resources on centring such as the links below:

[css3 pr align-self](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-self.asp)

[how to css image center](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_center.asp)

[css align](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to set your image in the center of screen Or in the center of a div?

If you want to set it in the center of screen   horizontally then you shoud set 
**margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;**

And if you want add text on image, you shoud set that image in the background of a div and add text in that div wherever you want

```
.imgdiv{ background: url(your IMG url) no-repeat center; 
-webkit-background-size: contain; 
-moz-background-size: contain;
 -o-background-size: contain; 
background-size: contain; 
height: 150px; width: 300px; 
}
.imgtxt{
   left:0; bottom:0;
}

<div class="imgdiv" >
     <span class="imgtxt">Your text</span>
 </div>
```